# Can programs be written with JavaScript that run Windows 8 terminal commands when a gui button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I know Windows 8 'apps' can be developed using web technologies but I haven't been able to find out if terminal commands can be run in the background using web technologies as an interface. I basically have mongoDB on my computer and it takes two terminal windows open to run it. I thought it might be a neat project to see if I could write a little app that is nothing more than a button that launches both commands behind the scenes saving me the hassle of going to the directories and running the commands manually for both terminal windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to launch apps via server-side JavaScript (e.g. node.js), use the [child_process module.](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

The workflow would be that in the windows 8 gui side, it will just issue a request to your own local server in node.js, then it would execute those commands.

Example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec("insert command here", function(err, stdout, stderr) { });
```

See examples [exec](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and spawn for more examples.

======

Another thing you can do is create a batch (.bat) file that contains those two commands needed for your mongodb instance and put that as a shortcut in the Windows 8 Start Screen.

It depends on what kinds of commands you need to execute, and when and where. If you plan to execute commands remotely, I'd assume server-side JS would be appropriate, but if you plan to execute commands locally, I think all you need is just batch scripting.